# phpimap class echo output from var dump

Tags: php, class, imap

i am strugeling to get date from my var dump.
i am usinge : https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap
and want to get data to output.
how can i "echo" this into php"?

```
object(IncomingMail)#10 (12) { 
    ["id"]=> string(4) "2937" 
    ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-12-01 10:44:24" 
    ["subject"]=> string(4) "roos" 
    ["fromName"]=> string(23) "test" 
    ["fromAddress"]=> string(15) "test" 
    ["to"]=> array(1) { ["test"]=> NULL } 
    ["toString"]=> string(21) "test" 
    ["cc"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["replyTo"]=> array(1) { 
    ["-------"]=> string(23) "test" } 
    ["textPlain"]=> string(5) " " 
    ["textHtml"]=> string(1612) "
```

added some more code :

```
// Get some mail
$mail = $mailbox->getMail($uid);
var_dump($mail);
var_dump($mail->getAttachments());
```

Thanks

Comment: if you're vardump'ing it, you've ALREADY got it in php.

Comment: Thats true only i want specif data on specif places in my php, how can i do that?

Comment: `echo $obj->replyTo['------']` should output test`. it's just an object, you deal with it like you would any other object.

Comment: when i add this line :    $obj = ''; and     echo $obj->replyTo['------']    i get    Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: yes, because `$obj = ''` will delete whatever was in $obj and replace it with an empty string. strings are NOT objects. Whatever you use to make that var_dump() is already an object.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: obj` when i do this : `echo $obj->replyTo['fromName'];`

Comment: Yeah, use $mail, not $obj; he meant that as a placeholder.